# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class not found - Opencart & QuickBooks Connector

Tags: php, class, opencart, quickbooks

Purchased an extension for OpenCart that enables connecting the store to a QuickBooks Desktop account.  It basically sets up a SOAP server to talk with the physical desktop device and communicate orders from the web server. The only problem is, it's not working!  lol

The error logs state the following:

```
[28-Feb-2023 17:19:24 America/Chicago] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'QuickBooks_WebConnector_Handlers' not found in /home/somesite/public_html/system/library/qbdt.php:48
Stack trace:
#0 /home/somesite/public_html/catalog/controller/account/qbdtwc.php(6): Qbdt->qbwc()
#1 /home/somesite/storage/modification/system/engine/action.php(79): ControllerAccountQbdtwc->index()
#2 /home/somesite/public_html/catalog/controller/startup/router.php(25): Action->execute(Object(Registry))
#3 /home/somesite/storage/modification/system/engine/action.php(79): ControllerStartupRouter->index()
#4 /home/somesite/storage/modification/system/engine/router.php(134): Action->execute(Object(Registry))
#5 /home/somesite/storage/modification/system/engine/router.php(123): Router->execute(Object(Action))
#6 /home/somesite/public_html/system/framework.php(169): Router->dispatch(Object(Action), Object(Action))
#7 /home/somesite/public_html/system/startup.php(104): require_once('/home/somesit...')
#8 /home/somesite/public_html/index.php(19): start('catalog')
#9 {mai in /home/somesite/public_html/system/library/qbdt.php on line 48
```

--- The first 50 lines of qbdt.php ---
`<?php
class Qbdt {

```
public function __construct($registry) {
    $this->db = $registry->get('db');
    $this->config = $registry->get('config');
$this->log = $registry->get('log');
}
```

/**
* SOAP endpoint for the Web Connector to connect to
*/
public function qbwc() {
require_once DIR_SYSTEM . '../QBDT/QuickBooks.php';

```
    $user = $this->config->get('module_opc_qbdt_app_user_name');

    $pass = $this->config->get('module_opc_qbdt_app_password');

    if (function_exists('date_default_timezone_set'))   {
        date_default_timezone_set($this->config->get('module_opc_qbdt_time_zone'));
    } else {
        date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
    }

    // Map QuickBooks actions to handler functions
    $map = array(
        QUICKBOOKS_ADD_DISCOUNTITEM => array( array( $this, '_addDiscountRequest' ), array( $this, '_addDiscountResponse' ) ),
        QUICKBOOKS_ADD_OTHERCHARGEITEM => array( array( $this, '_addOtherChargeRequest' ), array( $this, '_addOtherChargeResponse' ) ),
        QUICKBOOKS_ADD_ACCOUNT => array( array( $this, '_addAccountRequest' ), array( $this, '_addAccountResponse' ) ),
        QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER => array( array( $this, '_addCustomerRequest' ), array( $this, '_addCustomerResponse' ) ),
        QUICKBOOKS_MOD_CUSTOMER => array( array( $this, '_addCustomerRequest' ), array( $this, '_addCustomerResponse' ) ),
        QUICKBOOKS_DEL_LIST => array( array( $this, '_deleteListRequest' ), array( $this, '_deleteListResponse' ) ),
        QUICKBOOKS_ADD_INVENTORYITEM => array( array( $this, '_addProductRequest' ), array( $this, '_addProductResponse' ) ),
        QUICKBOOKS_MOD_INVENTORYITEM => array( array( $this, '_addProductRequest' ), array( $this, '_addProductResponse' ) ),
        QUICKBOOKS_ADD_SALESRECEIPT => array( array( $this, '_addSalesReceiptRequest' ), array( $this, '_addSalesReceiptResponse' ) ),
        QUICKBOOKS_IMPORT_CUSTOMER => array( array( $this, '_importCustomerRequest' ), array( $this, '_importCustomerResponse' ) ),
        QUICKBOOKS_IMPORT_ITEM => array( array( $this, '_importProductRequest' ), array( $this, '_importProductResponse' ) ),
    );

    // Catch all errors that QuickBooks throws with this function
    $errmap = array(
        '*' => array( $this, '_catchallErrors' ),
    );

    // Call this method whenever the Web Connector connects
    $hooks = array(
        QuickBooks_WebConnector_Handlers::HOOK_LOGINSUCCESS => array( array( $this, '_loginSuccess' ) ),    // Run this function whenever a successful login occurs
    );
```

`

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you!

I have reached out to the developers but they have been less than helpful.

What am I missing here?

Comment: it seems that the QuickBooks_WebConnector_Handlers class is not being found by the script. This class is likely defined in a separate file, which may not be included or loaded properly.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

This is the file from the lib that is being looked for:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/QuickBooks/WebConnector/Handlers.php

You probably just need to add a `require_once` line to pull that file in:

```
require_once DIR_SYSTEM . '../QBDT/QuickBooks/WebConnector/Handlers.php';
```

Have you tried that?